# Is there a performance difference between assigning before returning and directly returning in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc

Is there a performance difference between the two following functions, or is it handled by the compiler the same?

```
double f1(double a, double b) {
  return a + b;
}

double f2(double a, double b) {
  double sum = a + b;
  return sum;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Any modern compiler would emit the same code for that finally.

Comment: With C++17, directly returning(1st snippet) will use [mandatory copy elison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision#Mandatory_elision_of_copy/move_operations) while the second snippet can use [non-mandatory copy elison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision#Mandatory_elision_of_copy/move_operations)

Comment: @AnoopRana but that won't apply for POD types like this

Comment: @phuclv Yes, it applies to class objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a performance difference between the two following functions

One function contains two statements and the other contains one statement.

> or is it handled by the compiler the same?

They can be. Both functions have identical observable behaviour, so they may produce an identical program.

Answer (score 0):

From the practical side, it helps to see what compilers actually do with such a piece of code, see [this godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bfo4Gc3sY).

Turns out that starting from `-O1´ optimization level, g++ and clang for example create the exact same assembler instructions:

```
    addsd   xmm0, xmm1
    ret
```

Meaning the performance would of course also be exactly the same.